# почему не отображаются события?

Tags: javascript

есть такой скрипт, поздравлений, но работает не корректно, плавающие события (имены Виктор, именины Иван) почему-то не выводятся на страницу, помогите найти ошибку и исправить плиз

```js
var holidays = [{ // January | Январь
    1: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С новым годом !",
    },
    7: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С рождеством !",
    }
  },
  { // February | Февраль
    23: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С 23 февраля !",
    }
  },
  { // March | Март
    8: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С 8 марта !"
    }
  },
  { // April | Апрель
    12: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С днём космонавтики !",
    }
  },
  { // May | Май
    1: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С 1 мая !"
    },
    2: [ // Если праздников несколько, то в массив
      {
        start: 0,
        duration: 24,
        compliments: '<span class="birthday">С ДНЮХОЙ !</span>'
      },
      {
        start: "00:00:05",
        duration: "23:59:55",
        compliments: '<span class="holiday">С 2 мая !</span>'
      }
    ],
    9: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С 9 мая !"
    },
  },
  { // June | Июнь
    1: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С 1 июня, Всемирным днём родителей !"
    },
  },
  { // July | Июль
    3: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "3 июля, день независимости Республики Беларусь !"
    },
  },
  { // August | Август
    12: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "12 августа международный день молодёжи !",
    }
  },
  { // September | Сентябрь
    1: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "1 сентября, день знаний !",
    }
  },
  { // October | Октябрь
    1: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "1 октября, международный день пожилых людей !",
    }
  },
  { // November | Ноябрь
    7: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "7 ноября, день октябрьской революции !",
    }
  },
  { // December | Декабрь
    25: {
      start: 0,
      duration: 24,
      compliments: "С католическим рождеством !",
    },
  }
];

// =================== Добавил
addHolyday(4, 0, 1, // первое воскресенье мая
  {
    start: "00:00:01",
    duration: "23:59:55",
    compliments: '<span class="holiday">именины Виктор</span>',
  });
addHolyday(4, 0, -5, // первое воскресенье мая
  {
    start: 0,
    duration: 24,
    compliments: '<span class="holiday">именины Иван</span>',
  }
);

// ===================             
// Вычисляет число соответствующее дню недели в месяце
// month - месяц (0-11)
// wday - день недели 0 - воскр, 1 - понед ....
// index 1 первый день, 2 - второй ... -1 - последний, -2 предпоследний
function dayNWeek(month, wday, index) {
  const wday1 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), month).getDay()
  const dd = wday - wday1
  let dayw = 1 + (dd >= 0 ? dd : 7 + dd);
  const dtwday = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), month, dayw)
  const adayw = []
  while (new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), month, dayw).getMonth() == month) {
    adayw.push(dayw)
    dayw += 7
  }
  return adayw[(index > 0) ? index - 1 : adayw.length + index]
}
// добавляет праздник в массив holidays
function addHolyday(month, wday, index, hobj) {
  const dt = dayNWeek(month, wday, index);
  if (holidays[month][dt]) {
    if (!Array.isArray(holidays[month][dt]))
      holidays[month][dt] = [holidays[month][dt]];
  } else {
    holidays[month][dt] = [];
  }
  holidays[month][dt].push(hobj);
}
// ========================================         
function catholicDate(year) {
  // https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Гаусса_вычисления_даты_Пасхи
  var a = year % 19;
  var b = year % 4;
  var c = year % 7;
  var k = Math.floor(year / 100);
  var p = Math.floor((13 + 8 * k) / 25);
  var q = Math.floor(k / 4);
  var m = (15 - p + k - q) % 30;
  var n = (4 + k - q) % 7;
  var d = (19 * a + m) % 30;
  var e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + n) % 7;
  if (d === 29 && e === 6) return new Date(year, 3, 19);
  if (d === 28 && e === 6 && (11 * m + 11) % 30 < 19)
    return new Date(year, 3, 18);
  if (d + e > 9) return new Date(year, 3, d + e - 9);
  else return new Date(year, 2, 22 + d + e);
}

function orthodoxDate(year) {
  // https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Гаусса_вычисления_даты_Пасхи
  var a = year % 19;
  var b = year % 4;
  var c = year % 7;
  var d = (19 * a + 15) % 30;
  var e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 6) % 7;
  var f = d + e;
  return f <= 26 ?
    new Date(year, 3, 4 + f) :
    new Date(year, 4, f - 26);
}

//            const today = new Date("2 May 2021 07:00:00:001"); // d = new Date( "9 May 2021 00:00:00:001" )
const today = new Date("2 May 2021 00:00:05:001") // ======== для теста 2 мая 2021г. пасха, с 2 мая, с днюхой, именины Виктор, именины Иван ======

function getActualCompliments(now) {
  const result = [];



  holidays.forEach((vm, month) => {
    for (const day in vm) {
      let hlds = vm[day];
      if (!Array.isArray(hlds)) hlds = [hlds];
      for (const hld of hlds) {
        const [sth, stm = 0, sts = 0] = ('' + hld.start).split(':')
        const [drh, drm = 0, drs = 0] = ('' + hld.duration).split(':')
        const start = new Date(
          now.getFullYear(),
          month, +day, +sth, +stm, +sts
        ).getTime();
        const nt = now.getTime()
        const end = start + ((drh * 60 + (+drm)) * 60 + (+drs)) * 1000;
        if (start <= nt && nt < end) {
          result.push(hld.compliments);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  const caholic = catholicDate(now.getFullYear());
  const ortodox = orthodoxDate(now.getFullYear());

  if (
    caholic.getMonth() == now.getMonth() &&
    caholic.getDate() == now.getDate()
  )
    result.push("С католической пасхой!");

  if (
    ortodox.getMonth() == now.getMonth() &&
    ortodox.getDate() == now.getDate()
  )
    result.push('<span class="public_holiday">С православной пасхой!</span>');

  const radunitsa = new Date(ortodox);
  radunitsa.setDate(radunitsa.getDate() + 9);
  if (
    radunitsa.getMonth() == now.getMonth() &&
    radunitsa.getDate() == now.getDate()
  )
    result.push("С радуницей !");

  const trinity = new Date(ortodox);
  trinity.setDate(trinity.getDate() + 49);
  if (
    trinity.getMonth() == now.getMonth() &&
    trinity.getDate() == now.getDate()
  )
    result.push("С троицей!");

  return result;
}

const actualCompliments = getActualCompliments(today);

console.log(actualCompliments);

if (actualCompliments.length > 0) {
  const hollyday = document.getElementById("holiday");
  hollyday.style.display = "block";
  for (const cl of ["public_holiday", "holiday", "birthday"]) {
    for (const c of actualCompliments) {
      if (c.indexOf('class="' + cl + '"') >= 0) {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        hollyday.appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML = c;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#holiday {
  display: none;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
  border-radius: 12px/9px;
  padding: 2.5px 20px;
}

.public_holiday {
  color: hsl(340, 100%, 50%);
}

.holiday {
  color: hsl(210, 100%, 50%);
}

.birthday {
  color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
}

.public_holiday,
.holiday,
.birthday {
  display: block;
  font: bold 24px/20px serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.public_holiday,
.holiday,
.birthday {
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
  border-radius: 12px/9px;
  margin: 7.5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="block_time-data"></div>
</div>
<div id="holiday"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: what is "плавающие события"?

Comment: Igor, плавающие события, это события которые происходят ежегодно, в фиксированный месяц, но в разные даты, например, второе воскресенье месяца(от начала месяца), или в последнюю пятницу (первая пятница от конца месяца) и тому подобное...

Comment: что-то я не понял, по какому полю, в данных, можно понять, что праздник плавающий

Comment: Дмытрык, // ===== Добавил
addHolyday(4, 0, 1, // первое воскресенье мая
  {
    start: "00:00:01",
    duration: "23:59:55",
    compliments: '<span class="holiday">именины Виктор</span>',
  });
addHolyday(4, 0, -5, // первое воскресенье мая
  {
    start: 0,
    duration: 24,
    compliments: '<span class="holiday">именины Иван</span>',
  }
);

// =====             
// Вычисляет число соответствующее дню недели в месяце
// month - месяц (0-11)
// wday - день недели 0 - воскр, 1 - понед ....
// index 1 первый день, 2 - второй ... -1 - последний, -2 предпоследний